# Find value in column return TRUE/FALSE

Tags: r, return-value, where-clause, aggregate, string-matching

If this is my code:

```
df<-data.frame(speaker=c("nancyball","nancyball","wigglet","wigglet"),
               phrase=c("the cat is on the hat",
                        "the cat runs",
                        "the cat is under the bowl",
                        "a cat plays"))

prep.list<-c("on","under","in")
```

I want a new column (`df$kind`) added to `df` with a value of `T` or `F` a word from `prep.list` is in `df$phrase`.

There must be an easy way to do this.

Even better, I'd like `df$kind` to return a few different things, like if I also had:

```
verb.list<-c("plays","sings","sits")
```

I would get:

```
"prep, F, prep, verb"
```

I tried:
`where()` which won't coerce my column into a vector and 
`apply()` with `grep()` but it lost a dimension

Comment: Suppose if more than one `list` matches to a row in `df$kind`, what will be expected result?  Do you want to use `paste`?   For example, `prep_verb`

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
  df$kind <- grepl(paste(prep.list, collapse="|"), df$phrase)
  df
  #   speaker                    phrase  kind
  #1 nancyball     the cat is on the hat  TRUE
  #2 nancyball              the cat runs FALSE
  #3   wigglet the cat is under the bowl  TRUE
  #4   wigglet               a cat plays FALSE


 indx1 <- grepl(paste(prep.list, collapse="|"), df$phrase)
 indx2 <- grepl(paste(verb.list, collapse="|"), df$phrase)
```

After finding @Jaap's answer, I guess you wanted:

```
  df$kind <- c("F", "prep", "verb")[as.numeric(factor(1*indx1+2*indx2))] #updated based on comments from @alexis_laz
  df
  #  speaker                    phrase kind
 #1 nancyball     the cat is on the hat prep
 #2 nancyball              the cat runs    F
 #3   wigglet the cat is under the bowl prep
 #4   wigglet               a cat plays verb
```

#### Update

Suppose you have multiple `lists` and more than one `list` matches a particular `element` of `df$phrase`, one way is:

```
 new.list <- c("hat", "bowl", "howl")
 nm1 <- ls(pattern=".list")
 lst1 <- mget(nm1)
 indx2 <- sapply(names(lst1), function(x) {x1 <- gsub("\\..*", "", x)
                                indx <- grepl(paste(lst1[[x]], collapse="|"), df$phrase)
                                      c(NA, x1)[indx+1]})

   df$kind <- ifelse(rowSums(is.na(indx2))==ncol(indx2), "F", 
                apply(indx2, 1, function(x) paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse="_")))

   df
   #   speaker                    phrase     kind
   #1 nancyball     the cat is on the hat new_prep
   #2 nancyball              the cat runs        F
   #3   wigglet the cat is under the bowl new_prep
   #4   wigglet               a cat plays     verb
```

Comment: Nice! But I'm not sure how the `1+2*indx1+4*indx2` part works. Could you explain?

Comment: @Jaap I used  `1+2*...`, so that creates a unique numeric index `[1] 3 1 3 5` which I then convert it to `as.numeric(factor(..))` to get a sequence of numeric values `[1] 2 1 2 3` that can index the `c("F", "prep", "verb")` based on the order.

Comment: +1 for the powers of 2 encoding! Perhaps, it would be even more idiomatic something like `(indx1 * 1) + (indx2 * 2)` (i.e. indxN * 2^(N-1)). And, since you call, `factor`, I guess, you don't need `+ 1`?

Comment: @alexis_laz Thanks. yes, you are right.  `+1` is not that necessary.  Also, in the example the OP showed, there were no multiple matches to `df$phrase` with the vectors.  Perhaps, `paste` would be an option if such a situation comes.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @akrun's answer, you can combine the several comparisons with:

```
df$kind <- ifelse(grepl(paste(verb.list, collapse="|"), df$phrase), "verb",
                  ifelse(grepl(paste(prep.list, collapse="|"), df$phrase), "prep", F))
```

which gives:

```
    speaker                    phrase  kind
1 nancyball     the cat is on the hat  prep
2 nancyball              the cat runs FALSE
3   wigglet the cat is under the bowl  prep
4   wigglet               a cat plays  verb
```

If you explicitly want an `F` instead of `FALSE`, replace the `F` with `"F"` in the last `ifelse` statement.